# The Django test client redirects to the login page with a logged-in superuser

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

### The Problem

I am trying to connect a superuser to the Django test client, and then access a page in the Django administration interface with a GET method. However, I get a redirect to the login page, even though the superuser is properly logged in.

### The Code

```py
def test(self) -> None:
    client = Client()
    user = User.objects.create(username='user', is_superuser=True)
    client.force_login(user)
    response = client.get(f'/admin/management/establishment/', follow=True)

    print("Redirect chain\t", response.redirect_chain)
    print("Request user\t", response.wsgi_request.user)
    print("Is superuser\t", response.wsgi_request.user.is_superuser)
```

### The Output

```sh
Redirect chain   [('/admin/login/?next=/admin/management/establishment/', 302)]
Request user     user
Is superuser     True
```

### Additional Information

- Same result with a user having a password and an email
- Tested on a new Django project

### The Question

Do you know why I have this redirection and how I can avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem source

It seems that setting a user as superuser with `is_superuser=True` does not allow them to access the Django admin interface.

Only staffs can log in, so the `is_staff=True` attribute must be added to the user creation.

It's surprising that superusers are not considered staff by default.

### Solution

Creating the user with the following line does not redirect to the login page:

```py
user = User.objects.create(username='user', is_superuser=True, is_staff=True)
```